# Is there any way to import backup.sql file to an empty database with skip of some columns

Tags: mysql, import, mysqlimport

I have an SQL file having a dump of only a single table, say user table. Now I want to import this user table to another empty database with excluding some of its columns.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the original DB you can create the dump without some of the columns.
See for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/mysqldump-tables-excluding-some-fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to do it from cronjob, so need to do it from mysqldump command. or a command which provides sql file in one go.

Comment: If you have access to the DB you can have a view over the table with only the columns you want and use sqldump on that view. See details in this answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34889 .

Comment: Thanks, but it also not using mysqldump and provide output as a file and I want .sql.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to perform this in one go.

1. Use mysqlimport command into some php file `"script.php"` as

   `exec('mysqldump ....')`


   ?>
2. After this command, write a code into script.php file to execute mysql query to remove/empty columns from the newly created database.
3. set this php script into cron job as

   php -f script.php